# how to overwrite ( or update) shape of width and hiehgt in konva js?

Tags: konvajs

I am using konva js in my project. i am having doubt  how to  update already existing value of shape width and height.

Ex:

```
  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fill: "white",
  });
  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);
  
   var bg = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width:width ,
    height:height ,
    fill: 'white',
    draggable: false,
  });
  layer.add(bg);
 // ---------------------------------
 var update_shape=()=>{
   //i want to update here <-------------just calling this function
}
```

now i want to update above width and height values dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
shape.width(newWidth);
// or
shape.setAttr('width', newWidth);
// or
shape.setAttrs({ width: newWidth });
```